# What is up with MMS?

Tags: managed-metadata

Yesterday, I was able to run some script upload and update MMS type columns via script.

Today, the same script unable to get hold of the taxonomy store. I can see the whole tree from any site collection (site setting > term store mgmt). Why then following ps not working? REALLY FRUSTRATED WITH SHAREPOINT LACK OF DOCUMENTATION.

```
$site = "http://portal.company.com/legal"
$session = get-sptaxonomysession -site $site

if ($session.TermStores.Count > 0)
{
    $ts = $session.TermStores[0]
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Term Stores not found"
}
```

Comment: Looks like same issue as this guy but where is the FIX. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/89d1b927-59cf-4a28-ae7e-a274cc491695/

Comment: Tried this guy's solution but no luck. http://sharepointlearningcurve.blogspot.com/2010/04/taxonomysession-doesnt-show-my-term.html

Comment: Adding more spicy. When running the script from the app server it worked.